# Count elements and change css

Tags: jquery, css

http://jsfiddle.net/YvbhH/

I am trying to display only the first 5 li elements in the `#news` div.

If there is no li (try to erase them and run the script again) the `#nonews` div should appear and the `#news` div should disappear. 

If it's less than 5 items it sould calculate the height (newsli x30px)

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't close news correctly!

```
</div>
```

You're missing the `/`

As such, `#nonews` is a child of `#news`, and when you make `#news` dissapear they both go.

Darn little mistakes.

[Here's the working fiddle. All I did was close news properly](http://jsfiddle.net/K347Q/)

Comment: Right. Notice that you can use `$('#news').hide();` and `$('#news').show();`. Shortest to write.

Comment: @TRK Happy to help. When you have weird issues like this, I often recommend opening the page with Chrome's Developer Tools. If you look at the elements view of the page before the fix, the problem suddenly becomes clear (IMO)

Answer (score 1):

You calculated the 135px incorrectly, forgot to count the 3px margin in both above the first element and under the last element. Here's a corrected fiddle, with correct markup from the answer of @ngmiceli

http://jsfiddle.net/VesQ/YvbhH/1/

Answer (score 0):

dude got it....
close first div with id="news". I have updated your fiddle please check